# CompileAssemblyFromFile: Can I give the source in a rich text box to it?

Tags: c#, codedom

using CodeDOM I was able to compile the source code I had written in a separate file:

```
    CompilerResults results = codeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, @"C:\MyScript.cs");
    results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Script").GetMethod("Main").Invoke(null, null);
```

Is there a way that instead of reading that source code from a file - MyScript.cs - so I can just put a rich text box on the form and place the code in that?

Comment: why don't you want use file and read from it ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula : Project Requirements! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation of [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx): it contains a method [`CompileAssemblyFromSource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx) that takes one or more strings that contain the code to compile.

So, your code could look like:

```
CompilerResults results = codeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    parameters, codeFromTextBox);
```

Comment: Is it possible to compile code inside a .aspx file and emit the binary with this?